# Add dynamically form fields dependencies in js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am developing an app in Django. In my forms it is possible to have dependent fields. I would like to use [this](https://dstreet.github.io/dependsOn/#main) plugin. However, field dependencies may vary depending on the user's choices.
The fields in my forms look more or less like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name1" data-dependency="id_name2" class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_name1">
```

The `data-dependency` attribute indicates which fields this field depends on. So in this case the `name1` field will somehow depend on the `name2` field.

I wrote this sample script to dynamically add dependencies:

```
    $('document').ready(function(){
        var name = document.getElementById("id_name1");
        var data_dependency = name.getAttribute('data-dependency');
        var dependencies = data_dependency.split(";")
        var i =0;
        for(i=0; i<dependencies.length; i++){
            var d = dependencies[i];
            var elem = document.getElementById(d);

            $(name).dependsOn({
                '#id_name2' : {
                    values: ['yes']
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

At this point, I have a fixed id `#id_name2`  on which depends field  `name1` . Is there any way to pass on any element taken from the dependencies?

A simple working example (you only need to download two scripts):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dependsOn.min.js"></script>
    

    <script>
        $('document').ready(function(){
            var element = document.getElementById("myText2");
            var data_dependency = element.getAttribute('data-dependency');
            var dependencies = data_dependency.split(";")
            var i =0;
            for(i=0; i<dependencies.length; i++){
                var d = dependencies[i];
                var tmp = document.getElementById(d);

                $(element).dependsOn({
                    '#myText1' : {
                        values: ['yes']
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="myForm">
        <label for="myText1">Type yes</label>
        <input type="type" id="myText1">

        <label for="myText2">Input</label>
        <input type="text" id="myText2" value="" data-dependency="myText1">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you create working demo code ?

Comment: @Swati I edited the post and added.

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving the problem was to know that dependsOn accepts the dictionary as an argument.
It is enough to create a suitable dictionary and pass it on as an argument.
So the solution is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dependsOn.min.js"></script>
    

    <script>
        
        function get_id(element) {
            return '#' + element.id;
        };
        
        $('document').ready(function(){
            var element = document.getElementById("myText2");
            var data_dependency = element.getAttribute('data-dependency');
            var dependencies = data_dependency.split(";")
            var i =0;
            for(i=0; i<dependencies.length; i++){
                var d = dependencies[i];
                var tmp = document.getElementById(d);
                
                var data = {}
                data[get_id(tmp)] = {values: ['yes'] }

                $(element).dependsOn(data);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="myForm">
        <label for="myText1">Type yes</label>
        <input type="type" id="myText1">

        <label for="myText2">Input</label>
        <input type="text" id="myText2" value="" data-dependency="myText1">
    </form>

</body>
```